# linux - set date offset from BIOS date

Tags: linux, bios, date, locale

Linux can use BIOS clock in UTC or local time mode so it can add certain offset to BIOS time at OS level. Is it possible to do the same for date? I mean lets say I'd have 1999 year set in BIOS and Linux would still show 2015? Because I wouldn't like to have mess with files mod dates and due to irony of life I can't set proper date in BIOS...

Comment: Have you tried changing your CMOS battery?

Comment: how is it related? I need 1999 in BIOS *AND* correct data in linux. "How to change date in BIOS" is basically different question which doesn't solve my problem

Comment: You said "I can't set proper date in BIOS" ... not "I don't wan't to change the date in BIOS"